# Swift Changing Dynamically Created Label

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface

I have a program that needs to create dynamic tabs, and in each tab put a relevant data to that tab.
For testing purposes, I've tried to make a program that creates 1 tab dynamically and should display relevant data by calling a function.
It has 2 classes: `TabsController` which is hooked up to the Tab Controller on the stoty board, and `PageController` which is the class that should make the dynamic tabs.

The problem is, I do manage to make the dynamic page, but trying to update the label text doesn't update it - it stays with the "Test" value. I probably mess something up with the pages life cycles, but I can't understand what.

**TabsController:**

```
import Cocoa

class TabsController: NSTabViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        let page1 = PageController()
        page1.changePageNum("1")
        self.addChildViewController(page1)
    }
}
```

**PageController:**

```
import Cocoa

class PageController: NSViewController {
    var lblHeader = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(20, 20, 120, 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.lblHeader.stringValue = "Test"
        self.view.addSubview(self.lblHeader)

    }

    func changePageNum(_ pageNum: String) {
        self.title = "Page \(pageNum)"
        self.lblHeader.stringValue = "Page \(pageNum)"
    }
}
```

And while I'm on that, I'm having a really hard time finding literature for mac os swift programming. Usually what I find is for ObjC or iOS oriented. Anyone knows a good source for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use dispatch with main thread and update it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. Shouldn't it be done like this?: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            page1.changePageNum("1")
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating a new `PageController` every time your view appears. You'll eventually end up with hundreds of `PageController`s. Allocate it as a variable instead and add it as child in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class TabsController: NSTabViewController {
    var pageController = PageController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageControler.changePageNum("1")
        self.addChildViewController(page1)
    }
}
```

Ray Wenderlich has good Swift literature:
https://store.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: Thanks, it does manages to call the changePageNum correctly. But still the textfield is not being updated. Searching the web suggested that i should dispatch it to main queue as Salman proposed, but it doesn't work yet